# Bug en Sublime Text Ctrl + Z y Ctrl +S

Tags: sublimetext3

Mi problema es que cuando le doy a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, me tabula todo el fichero, y cuando le doy otra vez me lo quita. A veces me pasa lo mismo con <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ...

En las keys Bindings tengo:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl + z"], "command": "undo"},

{"keys": ["ctrl + s"], "command": "save"},
```

No lo entiendo, seguramente sea un paquete que me este dando conflicto
Emmet,TypeScript..

Y en la pestaña Edit me aparece a veces "Undo Emacs Tabstop to Spaces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>" ..

Si alguien puede ayudarme ..

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, tenia instalado el paquete **Emacs Tabstops** .Es lo que me estaba dando problemas.

Un saludo!

Comment: Que bueno que te hayas dado cuenta ya iba a responder jaja